# Why do not change DB, How to resave the rollbacked object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This code is unusual.
I am programming a Long Running Transactions(with Web API).
So, I need tricky program.
I want to resave the rollbacked object(`piyo2`).

```
piyo2 = nil
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  piyo1 = Piyo.find_by(id: 1)
  piyo1.name = 'hoge'
  piyo1.save!
  piyo2 = Piyo.find_by(id: 2)
  piyo2.name = 'foo'
  piyo2.save!
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
piyo2.save! # log show BEGIN COMMIT. But Not show execute SQL.
piyo2.name # keep foo. But DB no change.
```

My Solution.

```
piyo2 = nil
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  piyo1 = Piyo.find_by(id: 1)
  piyo1.name = 'hoge'
  piyo1.save!
  piyo2 = Piyo.find_by(id: 2)
  piyo2.name = 'foo'
  piyo2.save!
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
piyo2_retry = Piyo.find_by(id: piyo2.id) # one more find_by
piyo2_retry.update!(name: piyo2.name)
```

This is the best solution?
Why `piyo2.save! # log show BEGIN COMMIT. But No execute SQL.` this code not wok?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing the right thing, though your example leaves me with some confusion.

Here is the *why* of what you are seeing.

You have to refresh the state of the instance you have in hand.

Even though you rolled the transaction back, the instance in your hand still *thinks* it was persisted and has the new name. You can see this evidenced by calling:

```
puts piyo2.name        # foo
puts piyo2.persisted?  # true
puts piyo2.changed?    # falses
```

Rails is smart enough not to actually run SQL if the object is currently persisted and has no changes. You can prove this to yourself by loading any object and immediately trying to save it. You will see the BEGIN/COMMIT with no other SQL in the log/output.

Effectively your object is no longer in sync with the database. In order to get the state of your instance back in sync with the db you have to reload it:

```
piyo2.reload
```

This is what you are doing effectively. `Piyo.find piyo2.id`  generates the same exact SQL as reload. Reload is just semantically clearer.

Comment: `piyo2.reload` return to the original.  Need copy or clone `piyo2`?  lile `tmp_piyo = piyo2.clone`

Comment: clone is a valid method. it will reflect the state of what you have in hand. then you'll have to save it, of course. But that creates a brand new piyo, not persisting changes to the one you have in hand.